# Nginx try_files & rewrite & content type

Tags: nginx, content-type

I'm currently migrating from lighttpd to nginx.
I've got some weird files (don't ask why):
1. say a file named 'news', which actually should be more like news.txt
2. a file named '.html', which actually should be index.html

With lighttpd, simply rewrite those things would work.
Nginx would still locate those files with try_files or rewrite, but I've got no control of the content type returned. I mean if the file is named '.html', the content type is 'application/octet-stream'.

I know I can use more_set_headers to achieve that, but is there any other way to do that? I mean why does nginx think a file named '.html' not an html file?

Answer (score 1):

> I mean why does nginx think a file named '.html' not an html file?

A dot at the beginning in unix-like systems is usually used as the indicator of hidden files. In this case, a part after the dot isn't file extension.

> I know I can use more_set_headers to achieve that, but is there any other way to do that?

You should use the [`default_type`](http://nginx.org/r/default_type) directive instead of 3-rd party modules.

For example:

```
location =/.html {
    default_type text/html;
}
```

Comment: I tried like this:
`location = / {
        default_type text/html;
    }
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri/.html $uri.html $uri =404;`
got a 403.

Comment: The `try_files` directive isn't inherited. In your case it will work only for requests that isn't caught by locations.